# TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'response.productType')

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hey guys i'm somewhat new to Ajax but my code is throwing up this error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'response.productType') and I don't know why.  Here's the code, thanks in advance.  all of this is wrapped in document.ready

```
function handleLupGoBrowseResponse(response){
    if(response.productType == "MSG"){
        if(LOCALE == 'en_US'){
            $('p.success').html(lupSuccessEn);
            $(lupUpsellEn).insertAfter('.headerTopBar');
            //alert("yes"); remove for prod
        }else if(LOCALE == 'fr_CA'){
            $('p.success').html(lupSuccessFr);
            $(lupUpsellFr).insertAfter('.headerTopBar');
        }else if(LOCALE == 'ja_JP'){
            $('p.success').html(lupSuccessJp);
            $(lupUpsellJp).insertAfter('.headerTopBar');
        }

    }else{
        //alert("no"); remove for prod
        //alert(lupMobile); remove for prod
    }
}



if(lupAjaxUrl != ""){
    $.ajax({
        url: lupAjaxUrl,
        cache: false,
        pageCache: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: handleLupGoBrowseResponse
    });
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: the error is on this line: if(response.productType == "MSG"){

Comment: It probably means that `response` is null.  The error is worded that way because your code is assuming it can use the value of `response` as if it were a reference to an object.

Comment: Wow all of the current answers are wrong :)

Comment: Inspect the call in your browser's console and see what is being returned from the server.

Comment: And unless you added some magic, there's no parameter called `pageCache` ?

Answer (score 2):

The response of your ajax call is not an object, it is evaluated as null. Add a condition to the beginning of your function to test this value

```
function handleLupGoBrowseResponse(response){
    if(response) {
        // execute your code
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to do that.

Comment: It's really @Pointy 's comment that provided the correct answer here. But he's a real altruist so cheers for him!